# Will XNA Mouse Event work with Single Touch on Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, xna, touch, mouseevent

I have a game developed for Windows 7 in XNA which uses the Mouse Event only! There are buttons around the screen that the user plays with.

Will this same game work with Windows 7 Touch screens with a single touch? I do not need any multi-touch functionality.

If not, how do I get the touch event in XNA on a Windows 7 PC?

Comment: As far as I know, a touch device sends clicks like a touchpad for a laptop does. I'm pretty sure that tapping the screen will count as a click.

Comment: It looks like the answer is "yes" - but I'd like to see someone who can actually confirm it give the answer. In the mean time, here is a relevant blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/09/09/touch-input-on-windows-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touchscreens do send mouse events.

Though they might send mousestates pressed/released/moved a little bit differently depending on the model. For example the original single touch eeetop sometimes never sent a pressed state(got moved instead even if you just clicked), while the later multitouch versions worked as expected.